# Hexdump conversion string surrounded by escaped characters in format string

Tags: shell, command-line, hexdump

I am trying to get the following result from `hexdump`:

```
    78      79      7a
```

which is `"\t78\t\t79\t\t7a\t"`

Trying

```
echo -n xyz | hexdump -e '1/1 "\t%x\t"'
```

Results in an error:

```
hexdump: %  : bad conversion character
```

But

```
echo -n xyz | hexdump -e '1/1 "|%x|"'
```

Correctly yields

```
|78||79||7a|
```

Adding spaces:

```
echo -n xyz | hexdump -e '1/1 "\t %x \t"'
```

does *something*:

```
    t 78        t 79        t 7a
```

which is `"\tt 78\t\tt 79\t\tt 7a\t"` but I'm getting both the desired tabs *and* the literal letter `t` plus some unwanted space characters.

It works when using just a single trailing tab

```
echo -n xyz | hexdump -e '1/1 "%x\t"'
```

gives me

```
78  79  7a
```

which is `"78\t79\t7a\t"` but not for a single leading tab

```
echo -n xyz | hexdump -e '1/1 "\t%x"'
```

which gives me another error

```
hexdump: %A: bad conversion character
```

I'm not sure where that error is coming from since there is no `%A` anywhere.

According to the man page, `\t` should be a supported escape sequence and I'm treating it like any other character in printf.

> The format    is required and must be surrounded by double quote (" ")
>        marks.  It   is interpreted as a fprintf-style format string (see
>        fprintf(3)), with the following exceptions:
>
> ```
>  +o   An asterisk (*) may not be used as a field width    or precision.
>
>  +o   A byte count or field precision is required for each ``s'' con-
>      version character (unlike the fprintf(3) default which prints
>      the entire string if the precision is unspecified).
>
>  +o   The conversion characters ``h'',    ``l'', ``n'', ``p'' and ``q''
>      are not supported.
>
>  +o   The single character escape sequences described in the C    stan-
>      dard are supported:
>
>       NUL                 \0
>       <alert character>   \a
>       <backspace>         \b
>       <form-feed>         \f
>       <newline>           \n
>       <carriage return>   \r
>       <tab>               \t
>       <vertical tab>      \v
> ```

Comment: Is it possible your shell tries to expand single backslashes first? I.e., try with double backslashes.

Comment: Same error for leading `\\t`. Using bash and the entire arg is in a single quoted string so it *shouldn't* be doing any expansion on the shell side.

Comment: `hexdump: %\: bad conversion character` for using both `\\t%x\\t`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior [is actually a fixed, not so long ago, bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=776096). For affected versions there's a workaround: just put the leading backslash into a separate format string.

For example, the code you wanted would look like:

```
echo -n xyz | hexdump -e '"\t" 1/1 "%x"'
```