# How to insert "\x" into a hexdump format string on macOS?

Tags: macos, binary, 64-bit, hexdump

I've been using the below `hexdump` format string on Linux for displaying the contents of a binary file in C-style hex format `\xXX\xXX...`:

```
$ hexdump -v -e '1/1 "\\x%02x"' file.bin
hexdump: %?: bad conversion character
```

However, as can be seen above, the `\` in`\\` isn't escaped properly, with the result of an error.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Hexdump Issue is Macos-Only

This problem used to be a [hexdump bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=776096) on debian, but was fixed. I've tested this on FreeBSD, and it's fixed in the `October 29, 2014` version of hexdump.

The version of BSD hexdump on Macos (see `man hexdump`) has not been updated since `July 10, 2004` and still has this problem. For more info on trying to find the version of Macos utilities, this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37639496/how-can-i-check-the-version-of-sed-in-os-x) regarding sed is helpful.

#### hexdump

We can get around it by putting the `\x` in a separate format string. For more information on why this is necessary, this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34145188/hexdump-conversion-string-surrounded-by-escaped-characters-in-format-string) about escaping tabs is useful.

```
hexdump -v -e '"\\\x" 1/1 "%02x"' $file
```

Three backslashes are necessary to get a `\` literal with `x` following.

#### xxd

For sake of completeness, an xxd implementation takes more steps, but doesn't require formatting string shenanigans:

```
xxd -p $file | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/\(..\)/\\x\1/g'
```

Comment: Thanks, so it's a bug in macOS `hexdump` only? Wouldn't it be better to also but `1/1` in front of `\\\x`, or should the byte count be 0, so that format doesn't consume any bytes (I'm not sure)?

Comment: This bug applies to all forms of hexdump. The linked SO question has more information about the bug, which is [this Debian one](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=776096). Edited answer to link directly to the bug.

Comment: If you put 1/1 in front of \\\x, then a byte will be read and won't be added as '\\\x' is a string literal. So that byte will be dropped, and if you put 1/1 in front of \\\x, every other byte won't be output by hexdump

Comment: @Shuzheng if you think this is the correct answer, please mark it as such.

Comment: I just want to correct you that this bug is not present on current Debian 8.3.0: `echo -n ABCD | hexdump -v -e '1/1 "\\x%02x"'` results in `\x41\x42\x43\x44`.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. I've added more context. It looks like this is  a problem with Macos hexdump, but the BSD and Linux versions have been updated in their respective operating systems.

Comment: Do you know how to update the macOS version? Or where to download code to update it myself? I can't find any update using Brew.

Comment: @Shuzheng I would just use xxd, tr, and sed instead as shown above. If you need an answer, this would be a good question for https://apple.stackexchange.com.